# illustrator resetting reference point

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

Quick question on Illustrator.

Is there a shortcut or a quick way to reset reference point to center of object, when using rotation, skew, or reflect tool?

Answer (score 1):

.. switch tools.. then switch back...

Or check the 9 point origin box in the **Control Bar/Transform Panel/Properties Panel**... [image]

Comment: I was doing switch and switch back method. 9 points origin box, never tried. Great! Thanx.